# UpdateSelectInput not updating values in R Shiny modules

Tags: r, module, shiny, shinydashboard

The task I have is changing the value in the first should change the values in the second dropdown. I did have a similar issue when I was doing in a shiny app with server.r and UI .r. But since my code is getting difficult to manage I understand shiny modules is the way to go forward. So in the code below is app.r where I have the module, UI, and server all in one. With my understanding, I am able to render the UI and the dropdowns but the updateSelectInput doesn't seem to be working when I change my drop-down selections.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)

dropDownUI <- function(id, div_width = "col-xs-12 col-md-8") {

  ns <- NS(id)

  div(column(3, uiOutput(ns("class_level"))),
      column(
        width = 3,
        pickerInput(
          inputId = ns("selected_product"),
          label = h4("Product Family"),
          choices <- c("22","33","44"),
          width = "100%"
        )
      ))
}

dropDown <- function(input, output, session) {

  ns <- session$ns

  output$class_level <- renderUI({
    selectInput(
      "selected_class",
      label = h4("Classification Level"),
      choices = list(
        "apple " = "apple",
        "orange " = "orange"),
      selected = "orange"
    )})

  observeEvent(input$class_level, {
    ns <- session$ns

    if (input$selected_class == "apple") {
      choices <- c("foo","zoo","boo")
    } else if (input$selected_class == "orange") {
      choices <- c("22","33","44")
    } else {
      choices <- c("aa","bb","cc")
    }
    updateSelectInput(session,
                      inputId = ns("selected_product"),
                      label = h4("Product Family"),
                      choices = choices)
  })
}

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("aaa",tabName = "aaa"),
      menuItem("bbb", tabName = "bbb"),
      menuItem("ccc", tabName = "ccc")
    ))

    body <-   ## Body content
      dashboardBody(tabItems(
        tabItem(tabName = "aaa",
                fluidRow(dropDownUI(id = "dropdown")),
                fluidRow(chartTableBoxUI(id = "ATC_Topline"))) # render the tabBox inside a fluidRow

      ))

    # Put them together into a dashboardPage
    ui <-   dashboardPage(
      dashboardHeader(title = "Loyalty Monthly Scorecard"),
      sidebar,
      body
    )

  server = {
    shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

      MyData <- read.csv(file="ldb_data.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")

      callModule(chartTableBox, id = "ATC_Topline", data = MyData)
      callModule(dropDown, id = "dropdown")

    })
  }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I can't parse your app because of the following error message: `could not find function "chartTableBoxUI"`. At first glance, it seems the namespace-function `ns` should not be used in `updateSelectInput` since the namespace is implicitly passed with the `session` argument already. Also, always use `ns` in `renderUI` (in this case `ns("selected_class")`).

Comment: @GregordeCillia this issue has been resolved. I should mark it  so.Thank you.

Comment: how did you resolve it @GregordeCillia? Please can you post it in the "Answer" section?

Comment: @Sanjay Mehrotra sorry, but the code in the question is incomplete. There is a missing module as well as a missing dataset referenced in it. Therefore I can't really post a corrected version of this. The main idea is to only use `ns` inside `renderUI` and the UI-part of the module.  All the remaining "server-part" of the module (including updateXXX) should work without using module's namespace. @SNT could you make the code of this question reproducible so I can post a proper answer?